# python sqlalchemy get column names dynamically?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, associative

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection = create_engine('mysql://user:passwd@localhost:3306/db').connect()

result = connection.execute("select * from table")
for v in result:
        print v['id']
        print v['name']
connection.close()
```

how i can get TABLES COLUMNS NAMES dynamically? in this case `id` and `name`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can either find the columns by calling `result.keys()` or you can access them through calling `v.keys()` inside the `for` loop.

Here's an example using `items()`:

```
for v in result:
    for column, value in v.items():
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(column, value))
```

Answer (score 14):

### Most direct solution

Can't get any simpler than a one-liner solution using list comprehension. It also is the most direct method:

```
[col for col in result.keys()]
# return: ['id', 'name']
```

@Saul's answer also works, but you'll need to be careful about iterating over only the first element through each `cursor.description`, lest you get a bunch of `None` in each tuple of the returned list.

It also is less-efficient, because you need to iterate through the `ResultProxy`, access the `cursor.description` attribute and for each of them only retrieve the element at index 0.

Using `timeit` in Python with 500,000 iterations showed the speed difference (0.016 vs 0.011):

```
connection = create_engine('sqlite:///rcsample.db').connect()
result = connection.execute("select * from response")
def cursfunc():
    return [ i[0] for i in result.cursor.description ]
print(timeit.timeit("cursfunc()", setup="from __main__ import cursfunc", number=500000))
# return: 0.01606178
```

While the proposed solution completes in ~30% less time:

```
connection = create_engine('sqlite:///rcsample.db').connect()
result = connection.execute("select * from response")

def keysfunc():
    return [col for col in result.keys()]
print(timeit.timeit("keysfunc()", setup="from __main__ import cursfunc", number=500000))
# return: 0.01097001
```

In fact, my suspicion is that the time difference could be greater on a table with more columns than the obviously simplified example above.

### In Practice: keys and values

In practice, you'd probably want to print both the key and values dynamically. There are two ways you can go about it. The first:

```
results = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM salesperson')
[{column:value for column, value in result.items()} for result in results]
# returns: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 
# 'Margaret'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Anna'}]
```

Alternatively using unpacking:

```
rows = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM salesperson LIMIT 2').fetchall()
print([{**row} for row in rows])
# returns: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Margaret'}]
```

Both of these methods are direct and pythonic, while also exempt the programmer from having to specify (or know beforehand) the columns names explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

something like this

`headers=[ i[0] for i in result.cursor.description ]`

same question here [return column names from pyodbc execute() statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704305/return-column-names-from-pyodbc-execute-statement)