# return column names from pyodbc execute() statement

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(databasez)
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID, NAME AS Nickname, ADDRESS AS Residence FROM tablez""")
DF = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

This is fine to populate my pandas DataFrame. But how do I get

```
DF.columns = ['ID', 'Nickname', 'Residence']
```

straight from *cursor*? Is that information stored in *cursor* at all?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question 100,000 times.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can get the columns from the cursor description:

`columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]`

Comment: In case anyone is curious what the other values in `.description` mean:  https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#attributes

Comment: When I tried this, I got a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Comment: A "NoneType" TypeError will occur when the ```description``` attribute is ```None``` due to no rows being returned, as described here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki

Answer (score 53):

Recent pandas have a higher level [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries) functions that can do this for you

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(databasez)
DF = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT ID, NAME AS Nickname, ADDRESS AS Residence FROM tablez", cnxn)
```

Answer (score 15):

In case you are experiencing the `NoneType` error from the code provided by [Matti John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452002/matti-john), make sure to make the `cursor.description` call *after* you have retrieved data from the database. An example:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Improving on the previous answer, in the context of pandas, I found this does exactly what I expect:

```
DF.columns = DataFrame(np.matrix(cursor.description))[0]
```