# Print pyodbc column value with variable holding column name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the value of a column from a pyodbc query using variables so i can do some dynamic stuff.

```
columnName = "test1"

query = "SELECT test1,test2,test3 FROM testTable"
pyodbc.cursor.execute(query)
row = pyodbc.cursor.fetchone()

print(row.columnName)
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707465/1394353

Comment: not wanting to get column name.  I am trying to call the column that i have as a variable in the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable like the one below to get the values for that column:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pyodbc

columnName = "test1"
query = "SELECT {} FROM testTable".format(columnName)
cursor.execute(query)

DF = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Also you can get the columns data:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Which is returned as a data tuple.

It is better not to take your command parameters from the user or the outside space because you may get a SQL injection attack.
Cursor parameters are also used to set `values` so you can use the above solution and is not used for this purpose.

You can access all attribute of cursor in : https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#attributes

Comment: not wanting to get column name.  I am trying to call the column that i have as a variable in the print statement.

Comment: @jman_pS I changed answer to what you wanted.