# SQLAlchemy execute() return ResultProxy as Tuple, not dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
query = """
SELECT Coalesce((SELECT sp.param_value
                 FROM   sites_params sp
                 WHERE  sp.param_name = 'ci'
                        AND sp.site_id = s.id
                 ORDER  BY sp.id DESC
                 LIMIT  1), -1) AS ci
FROM   sites s
WHERE  s.deleted = 0
       AND s.id = 10 

"""

site = db_session.execute(query)
# print site 
# <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x033E63D0>

site = db_session.execute(query).fetchone()
print site  # (u'375')
print list(site) # [u'375']
```

Why does SQLAlchemy return tuples, not dicts, for this query? I want to use the following style to access the results of the query:

```
print site.ci
# u'375'
```

Comment: * *confused*  * you select `"sp.param_value"` but expect the result proxy to have a member called `"ci"` ? you can use result proxies like a dict, but you'd use something like `print site['param_value']`

Comment: resultproxy return tuple, i want, thats resultproxy return dict `site['ci']` or `site.ci`

Comment: I agree with @Gryphius. You can try like this `print site['ci']`

Comment: @Gryphius, @Syed Habib M, its isnt works! ResultProxy return tuple, not dict and not somethink other!!! `(u'375')`

Comment: Did you try that? Are you sure there is column name like 'ci' in Coalesce table?

Comment: check resultproxy like `print site.keys()`. Make sure the result has a value like 'ci'.

Comment: nvm my earlier comment, I didn't notice the `AS ci` part in your query first

Answer (score 66):

This is an old question, but still relevant today.  Getting SQL Alchemy to return a dictionary is very useful, especially when working with RESTful based APIs that return JSON.

Here is how I did it using the `db_session` in Python 3:

```
resultproxy = db_session.execute(query)

d, a = {}, []
for rowproxy in resultproxy:
    # rowproxy.items() returns an array like [(key0, value0), (key1, value1)]
    for column, value in rowproxy.items():
        # build up the dictionary
        d = {**d, **{column: value}}
    a.append(d)
```

The end result is that the array `a` now contains your query results in dictionary format.

As for how this works in SQL Alchemy:

- The`db_session.execute(query)` returns a `ResultProxy` object
- The `ResultProxy` object is made up of `RowProxy` objects
- The `RowProxy` object has an `.items()` method that returns key, value tuples of all the items in the row, which can be unpacked as `key, value` in a `for` operation.

And here a one-liner alternative:

```
[{column: value for column, value in rowproxy.items()} for rowproxy in resultproxy]
```

From the docs:

> class sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy(parent, row, processors, keymap)
>
> Proxy values from a single cursor row.
>
> Mostly follows “ordered dictionary” behavior, mapping result values to the string-based column name, the integer position of the result in the row, as well as Column instances which can be mapped to the original Columns that produced this result set (for results that correspond to constructed SQL expressions).
>
> has_key(key)
>   Return True if this RowProxy contains the given key.
>
> items()
>   Return a list of tuples, each tuple containing a key/value pair.
>
> keys()
>   Return the list of keys as strings represented by this RowProxy.

Link:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy.items

Comment: I believe you meant to assign the result of `session.execute()` to `resultproxy`, like so:

`resultproxy = db_session.execute(query)`

Comment: This seems to be working for me with less typing `[dict(row) for row in resultproxy]`

Comment: if you iterate through it, it seems to not be iterable again?

Answer (score 21):

Did you take a look at the [ResultProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) docs?
It describes exactly what @Gryphius and  @Syed Habib M  suggest, namely to use `site['ci']`.

The `ResultProxy` does not "return a tuple" as you claim - it is (not surprisingly) a proxy that behaves (e.g. prints) like a tuple but also supports dictionary-like access:

From the docs:

> Individual columns may be accessed by their integer position,
>   case-insensitive column name, or by schema.Column object. e.g.:
>
> row = fetchone()
>
> col1 = row[0]    # access via integer position
>
> col2 = row['col2']   # access via name
>
> col3 = row[mytable.c.mycol] # access via Column object.

Comment: Not working on sqlachemy 1.1. The ResultProxy elements are just tuples. The only way seems to be accessing the result.keys() and building your own dicts with that.

Comment: @tothemario The docs for (currently) version 1.2.x still contain my copy & pasted snippet from above. So it seems the ResultProxy is still not just a tuple.

Answer (score 7):

I've built a simple class to work like a database interface in our processes. Here it goes:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
class DBConnection:
    def __init__(self, db_instance):
        self.db_engine = create_engine('your_database_uri_string')
        self.db_engine.connect()

    def read(self, statement):
        """Executes a read query and returns a list of dicts, whose keys are column names."""
        data = self.db_engine.execute(statement).fetchall()
        results = []

        if len(data)==0:
            return results

        # results from sqlalchemy are returned as a list of tuples; this procedure converts it into a list of dicts
        for row_number, row in enumerate(data):
            results.append({})
            for column_number, value in enumerate(row):
                results[row_number][row.keys()[column_number]] = value

        return results
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily convert each result row to a dictionary by using `dict(site)`.
Then `site['ci']` would be available if `ci` column is exists.

In order to have `site.ci` (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084672/487460):

```
from collections import namedtuple
Site = namedtuple('Site', site.keys())
record = Site(*site)
```

Answer (score 4):

This may help solve the OPs question.  I think the problem he was having is that the row object only contained column values, but not the column names themselves, as is the case with ORM queries where the results have a **dict** attribute with both keys and values.

[python sqlalchemy get column names dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947616/python-sqlalchemy-get-column-names-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I found is using **list comprehension with calling dict() func on every RowProxy**:

```
site = db_session.execute(query)
result = [dict(row) for row in site]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Essential SQLAlchemy book:

> A ResultProxy is a wrapper around a DBAPI cursor object, and its main
> goal is to make it easier to use and manipulate the results of a
> statement

Simple select example:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

stmnt = select([cookies])
result_proxy = connection.execute(stmnt)
results = result_proxy.fetchall()
```

Results going to be like this:

```
# ID, cookie_name, quantity, amount

    [
     (1, u'chocolate chip', 12, Decimal('0.50')),
     (2, u'dark chocolate chip', 1, Decimal('0.75')),
     (3, u'peanut butter', 24, Decimal('0.25')),
     (4, u'oatmeal raisin', 100, Decimal('1.00'))
    ]
```

It makes handling query results easier by allowing access using an **index**, **name**, or **Column object**.
Accessing cookie_name in different ways:

```
first_row = results[0]
first_row[1]
first_row.cookie_name
first_row[cookies.c.cookie_name]
```

These all result in u'chocolate chip' and they each reference the exact same data element in the first record of our results variable. This flexibility in access is only part of the power of the ResultProxy.

We can also leverage the ResultProxy as an iterable:

```
result_proxy = connection.execute(stmnt)
for record in result_proxy:
    print(record.cookie_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method uses list comprehensions, it receives a sql alchemy rowset object and returns the same items as a list of dictionaries:

```
class ResultHelper():

@classmethod
def resultproxy_to_list(cls, sql_alchemy_rowset):        
        return [{tuple[0]: tuple[1] for tuple in rowproxy.items()} 
                                    for rowproxy in sql_alchemy_rowset]
```

Answer (score -1):

As you call `db.execute(sql).fetchall()`, you can easily use the following function to parse the return data to a dict:

```
def query_to_dict(ret):
    if ret is not None:
        return [{key: value for key, value in row.items()} for row in ret if row is not None]
    else:
        return [{}]
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use pandas to load results and columns name from a generic table. This generates a list of records:

```
qry = session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM mytable"))

df = pd.DataFrame(qry.fetchall(), columns=qry.keys())
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```