# Get column names Dynamically with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am querying sqlite db with SQLAlchemy like this:

```
import db

...

results = session.query(table).all()
        for result in results:
            print result
            print "how to print column name?"
```

Here is a snippet from db class:

```
class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "devices"
    name = Column(String(250), primary_key=True)
    location = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
```

Attempting to use ".column_descriptions" on result as per the documentation throws "'list' object has no attribute 'column_descriptions'" error.

What is the proper way of getting column names dynamically along with the values? I want this so I can build a single function to handle json conversion of all queries instead of repeating code all over the place.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947616/python-sqlalchemy-get-column-names-dynamically documents `result.keys()`. Which is, what you probably want.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Device.__table__.columns` to get the list of columns in your `Device`  model in your code. These are `Column` objects and you can get the name by using `.name` on them while iterating. Then when you query, you can just use `getattr` or something to get the values that you need.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
col_names = Device.__table__.columns.keys()  # This gets the column names
sample_row = Device.query.first()  # I just query for a random row
required_values = {name: getattr(sample_row, name) for name in col_names}
# This is a dictionary comprehension
```

You can also use the `select` syntax, perhaps.

**EDIT2:**

Here is an article on [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

Okay, so what this dictionary comprehension does is that it gets the keys as the name of column, and the values as the values of corresponding columns from the sample row that I queried for.

You wanted to print a `list`, so we can do that like this:

Replace the dictionary comprehension line with this.

```
print([getattr(sample_row, name) for name in col_names])
```

This will print the values from that row in a list, but you don't get the column names.

But for that you can create a list of tuples.

```
print([(name, getattr(sample_row, name)) for name in col_names])
```

But an easier way for you to do this probably would be to use the select syntax instead which is provided by SQLAlchemy.

Docs here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#tutorial-selecting-data

Comment: I was able to get column names in the for loop but can't get the values now. There is no clear documentation I can find on getattr. I tried getattr(Device, column.name) but it does not output a value. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I edited my answer with an example. See if that works for you.

Comment: I am a little unclear by the example (I am new to python). Could you provide example showing how to print the column name and column value in a simple for in loop?

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: I am getting "selectQuery error occurred: getattr(): attribute name must be string" error. "print sample_row" outputs "<db.Device object at 0x7f70a3aeb390>" presumably because it is not being looped over and so is not a string value. I also don't understand the way you are using the for in loop. Can you make it more readable by using the first code snippet in the question as a starting point?