# Get column names from raw query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm executing a raw query with SQLAlchemy. Is there a way to get the rows returned as dicts that contain column names (equivalent of DictCursor in MySQLdb) ?
Code:

```
sql = 'select * from table'

rows = engine.execute(text(sql))

for row in rows:
    print row
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. From this : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#basic-usage it looks like it's already returning a row "dict"-like structure. Maybe you could try row.__dict__ to print the content [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10370224/154607).

Comment: Ha, indeed. The object returned implements the __getitem__ operator. The default conversion to str is just a list format. Excellent, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python sqlalchemy get column names dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947616/python-sqlalchemy-get-column-names-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
     sql = 'select * from table'

     rows = engine.execute(text(sql))
     columns = None
     for row in rows:
         if columns is None:
             columns = row.keys()
         print(dict(zip(columns, row)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use some parser like this bellow. In this case will return a list with dicts inside, but you can change it to fit your needs.

```
def result_cursor_to_list(rows):
    data = []
    info = rows.keys()
    for row in rows:
        line = {}
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            line[info[i]] = col
        data.append(line)
    return data
```