# Iterate each column of SQLAlchemy ResultProxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I iterate each column of a `resultproxy` object?

I've tried an answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454618/506565):

```
for col in class_mapper(obj.__class__).mapped_table.c)
```

Gets this error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy' is not mapped
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947616/python-sqlalchemy-get-column-names-dynamically, but I'm not sure if by "columns" you mean the keys or the values.

Comment: i want both key and value of the columns

Answer (score 3):

A `RowProxy` is not a mapped class, as the error is telling you. It represents a lower level of abstraction and models a database result row "directly" – no ORM involved. [Reading the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy), a `RowProxy` is partly akin to an ordered dictionary, and provides the mapping interface, so you can use [`keys()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy.keys) and [`items()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy.items) to iterate over keys and key, item tuples respectively. If you iterate over a `RowProxy` instance, you get the values.

So if you want to iterate over the key, value tuples of a row:

```
for row in result:
    for key, value in row.items():
        pass
```